# How can I set columns to NA in data.table most effectively?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to set certain columns to NA. Example:

```
DT2 <- data.table(Id = rep(c(1,2,3),each = 20),
                 x1 = rnorm(20),
                 x2 = rnorm(20),
                 x3 = c(NA,NA,rnorm(18)))
DT2[,2] <- NA # sets the second column NA
```

Surprisingly, `DT2[,c(F,T,F,F)] <- NA` does not work in this case, one needs to use `which`.
However the above seems to be rather slow on big data tables when you set many columns by index to `NA`. I wonder if there is a better way, maybe by using `set`?
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: `datatable` is ambiguous.   What language/DBMS are you working in?

Comment: It would be best to use the column name, and assign by reference `DT2[, x1 := NA]`.  Using the index is more likely to result in a mistake.  What if you use the wrong index accidentally?

Comment: Ok, but what if I delete the columns on a condition? So basically I have the index of columns to delete. With a dataframe it its very easy: `df[,ind] <- NA`.

Comment: I would do `DT2[, (names(DT2)[ind]) := NA]` if you really need to use an index.

Comment: Thanks, but that throws an error: `Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query (duplicates detected)`. Actually some of my columns do have the same name (it makes sense in my case even if is usually a bit odd)

Comment: If you have columns with repeating names, you can use the column numbers there, I think, `DT[, (ind) := NA]` similarly, `set` iterating `j` over `ind` should work fine. Referring to cols by number instead of name is discouraged, though.

Comment: @Frank thank you very good comments. I tried both solutions and they both work. Should've made an answer out of it!

Comment: You can go ahead and post an answer yourself, fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Frank pointed out one needs to use `:=` to increase speed, e.g. with the above example:

```
DT[, (c(2,3)) := NA]
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the column position to update the values, it is generally better to code using the column names to prevent problems if the column order changes.  The following shows how to set all values for either a single column or multiple by name

```
library(data.table)

DT2[, x1 := NA]
DT2[, c("x1", "x3") := NA]
```

If you want to use `data.frame` syntax (it's actually faster with small data sets)

```
DT2[, "x1"] <- NA
DT2[, c("x1", "x3")] <- NA
```

Comment: I do know how to use colnames, but if I have thousands of columns with a random name pattern, how am I supposed to know the names when I test for a condition, e.g. let's say a certain amount of non-na's per column? The only way I know of is to use colindices instead of names.

Comment: if you're testing the columns to return an index is fine as it will select the correct columns irrespective of order.  The question appeared that you were hard-coding the column number which can create problems.